# I try to change the background color at on small app in html css js

Tags: javascript, css

I try to change the background color at on small app in html css js
one snap of this is:

```
var myoutput = document.getElementById("output");

function roundNum(){
AlphaValue=0.4;
RedValue=255;
GreenValue=0;
BlueValue=0;
outputColor=[RedValue,GreenValue,+BlueValue,AlphaValue];
return outputColor;
}
myColor=roundNum();
myColor1=myColor[0];
myColor2=myColor[1];
myColor3=myColor[2];
myColor4=myColor[3];
myoutput.style.backgroundColor ="( 
rgba("+myColor1+","+myColor2+","+myColor3+","+myColor4+");";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `(` from the first of your string, And remove `;` at the end.

Change:

```
myoutput.style.backgroundColor ="(rgba("+myColor1+","+myColor2+","+myColor3+","+myColor4+");";
```

To:

```
myoutput.style.backgroundColor ="rgba("+myColor1+","+myColor2+","+myColor3+","+myColor4+")";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of syntax issues there. You can not define multi-line strings with double or single quotes use backticks instead. And `rgba` does not start with a parenthesis before `r` and you done need a semicolon at the end;

```
myoutput.style.backgroundColor = `rgba(${myColor1},${myColor2},${myColor3},${myColor4})`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this

```js
const red = () => {
  const r = 255, g = 0, b = 0, a = 1;
  return `${r},${g},${b},${a}`;
}

document.body.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${[red()]})`;
```

```html
<html>
<body></body>
<html>
```